# How can I overload the operator += to add two class objects

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am currently taking a course on C++ at my uni. We are discussing pointers and overloading operators at the moment. The task is about English length units (feet and inches).

I want to overload the `operator+=`. And I want the result to be something like this:

```
d3 = d1 += d2; // d1, d2, d3 are class objects. Lets say d1(3, 4) and d2(1, 3). So the result should be d3(4, 7)
```

First of all, there is a class called `EnglishDistance` (assume that all constructors are correctly created)

```
class EnglishDistance
{
private:
    int f, i;
public:
    EnglishDistance(int x, int y);
    EnglishDistance();

    // Do some other stuff
}
```

Inside this class, among other things, I have already implemented the overloading of `operator+` (which works OK):

```
EnglishDistance operator+(EnglishDistance d) {
        EnglishDistance temp;

        temp.f = f + d.f;
        temp.i = i + d.i;

        // Some checks (if inches are >= 12 I will subtract 12 inches and add 1 feet)

        return temp;
}
```

And this is what I got so far about the `operator+=`

```
EnglishDistance& operator+=(EnglishDistance& d) {

        *this += d

        // This is the check I was talking about. Only in this instance I am applying it on a pointer.
        while (this->i >= 12) {
            this->i -= 12;
            this->f++;
        }

        return *this;
}
```

When I try to run this, I get an unhandled exception on Visual Studio (stack overflow), so obviously I have messed it up.

Can someone point out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `*this += d` is essentially `this->operator+=(d);`, which is the function you currently are in. This is infinite recursion. Since you've already implemented `operator+`, implement `operator+=` in terms of `operator+` instead (perhaps `*this = *this + d;`).

Comment: And the parameter should be `const EnglishDistance &`, for ***both*** overloaded operators, both `+` and `+=`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you, that did the trick! Didn't realize that I was calling on the overloaded operator (thought it would do the default function).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Answers go in the answer section. Simple.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: It would make more sense to implement `operator=` in terms of `operator+=`, no?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I will be sure to ask my tutor and do some research on this (since I am a newbie to this language), but why would I need the 'const'? The code, now, runs OK.

Comment: Please don't get into the nasty habit of naming things with one letter while you are still in the university. Change I to inches and f to feet. We call this self documenting code. If someone was to read your code where all variables are one letter, they will not know what they represent without your telling them. This makes for angry developers on the job.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes, it would make more sense to implement `operator+` in terms of `operator+=` but OP had already implemented `operator+`. That's definitively the kind of thing that should be included in an answer. But as you helpfully point it, it was only a comment.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Comments aren't an excuse to knowingly give bad advice, particularly since we cannot peer review them. Comments are only for requesting clarification from the OP. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz You are right and I do name my variables in a way to identify their purpose in other languages I use and I am more familiar with (like Java, especially with Android Studio, and C#). It's just that I am just starting learning this language and I prefer to pay attention to how things are done instead of using good programming habits at this stage.

Comment: Now, try to declare a function that returns an `EnglishDistance`, such as `EnglishDistance foo();`, and try to add the results: `EnglishDistance bar=foo()+foo();`. Unless the parameter to `operator+` is a `const` reference (and `operator+` must also be a const method, which I forgot to mention), this will not compile.

Comment: By the way, England switched to metric decades ago. Your class would be called `AmericanDistance` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 *this += d
```

Ignoring the fact that this line won't compile (missing semicolon), it's also logically senseless; inside the function that implements this operation, you're invoking the operation again!

That'll result in an infinite chain of function calls, eventually smashing your stack to pieces and causing your program to crash.

Instead of just repeating how you want the function to be used, you actually need to tell the computer how it should be *implemented*.

I suspect you meant this:

```
this->f += d.f;
this->i += d.i;
```

*(the `this->` can be omitted, though)*

Comment: Well, I missed the semicolon in the copy - paste procedure from Visual Studio. :D Apart from that, using directly the members of my class to do it, was my first move (it did work). However, in this instance I want to use pointers, pass by reference etc. in order to achieve the functionality I was after.

Comment: Strange; copy/paste usually doesn't drop characters.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by that. You can "use pointers" and "pass by reference" until the cows come home but, at some point, you have to tell your computer what to do with your variables.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, *this += d is calling EnglishDistance & operator+=(EnglishDistance& d), and then hitting *this += d, which is calling EnglishDistance & operator+= and on and on, until the stack overflows.

You really don't need "this" at all in any of your code thus far. I think it is confusing you anyway. Feel free to omit it completely and just use the names of the members directly.

Also, name your members appropriately with full meaningful names. Your future colleagues will thank you.

```
EnglishDistance & operator+=(EnglishDistance & rhs)
{
    // Convert to inches when adding
    m_inches += rhs.m_inches + rhs.m_feet * 12;

    // Now calculate the feet
    m_feet   += m_inches / 12;
    m_inches = m_inches % 12; // modulo operator gives remainder

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Now, back to the algorithm - I haven't done a thorough analysis but I'm not convinced that it is correct. So, either (a) it isn't, or (b) it is but this code is not very clear and should be improved, so that it can be understood at first glance.

Comment: @BoundryImposition Feel free to test it. If you have a suggested improvement, feel free to suggest it as well. I feel like it is quite straight forward, but am open to suggestions.

Comment: I gave you an opportunity to demonstrate that it is correct, but okay. Unless you can show that it's right and show your working, it's not really something we should be recommending to a language newcomer.

Comment: You are asking me to prove something as simple as 1+1=2, I don't know how to break it down any further for you. It has comments in case he doesn't know what the modulo operator is. This is how I would code such a problem in the real world. If you see an error, point it out. burden of proof is on you. It passes my tests here. It is not my intention for a newcomer to turn in my work as their own for an assignment anyway, but rather to read my example, look up parts of it that are fuzzy, or ask questions, and learn from it

Comment: It is not as simple as 1+1=2, and the burden of proof is _not_ on me. You're giving code to the OP to use and saying "it does _X_". _You_ need to show that it is fit for purpose, not some random other reader of your answer. At this point you are being deliberately difficult apparently? If it really is as simple as 1+1=2 then you could spend a comment explaining it to me instead of three comments berating me :(

Comment: No, I really don't. I don't _have to_ do anything at all. I am not going to go on for 1000 replies about it. If you see an error, point it out. I've got to get back to work.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition If you think it's wrong, show why or how you think it's wrong. If you think it's unclear, explain specifically what you think is unclear about it. Otherwise, if you disagree with the answer, downvote it. What you did was, at least IMO, sabotage.